# Python calculator - Having issues using 3 number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started to learn python and I created a calculator.
I'm having troubles with doing 3 number operation with multiplication and division.
I set the variable Number3 to zero so that if you don't have a third number it won't affect the operation, so it would be `1+1+0= 2`, but if it's not `+` or `-` it will end up affecting the answer.
So what I did was create a variable Number4 with a value of 1 and just add it to the `elif` statements for multiplication and division.
However, I feel like it sloppy and there is a better way of getting the effect.   What would be the best way to do this?

```
print ("Python calculator")
print ("""
Select an operation below
1: Add
2: Sub
3: Mult
4: Div

""")

def add(x, y, z):
   return x + y + z
def sub(x, y, z):
   return x - y - z
def mult(x, y, z):
   return x * y * z
def div(x, y, z):
   return x / y / z

Operation = input ("Enter Operation Number")

Number1 = int(input ("Enter Your First Number"))
Number2 = int(input ("Enter your Second Number"))
Number3 = (0)

More = input ("Do you have more numbers? (Yes or No)")
if More == "yes" or More == "Yes":
    Number3 =int(input ("What is your other number?"))
    print ("calculating")
else:
    print ("calculating")

if Operation == '1':
   print(add(Number1,Number2,Number3))

elif Operation == '2':
   print(sub(Number1,Number2,Number3))

elif Operation == '3'and More != "Yes":
  Number4 = 1
  print(mult(Number1,Number2,Number4 ))

elif Operation == '3':
   print(mult(Number1,Number2,Number3 ))

elif Operation == '4'and More != "Yes":
  Number4 = 1
  print(div(Number1,Number2,Number4 ))

elif Operation == '4':
   print(div(Number1,Number2,Number3 ))
else:
   print("Invalid inputs")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set

```
Number3 = None
```

Then internalize the logic into the functions with default parameters

```
def add(x, y, z=None):
   return x + y + (0 if z is None else z) 
def sub(x, y, z=None):
   return x - y -  (0 if z is None else z) 
def mult(x, y, z=None):
   return x * y * (1 if z is None else z) 
def div(x, y, z=None):
   return x / y /  (1 if z is None else z)
```

Then all of these should work as expected

```
print(mult(Number1,Number2))
print(mult(Number1,Number2,1))
print(mult(Number1,Number2,0))
print(mult(Number1,Number2,None))
```